# Не могу установить ОС с флешки NTFS

Tags: файловая-система, ос, ntfs

Здраствуйте.
Я скачала ISO-образ 32-битной полной Debian 10. Попробовала при помощи программы WinSetupFromUsb установить на флешку с файловой системой FAT32. Выдала ошибку типа: "Преувеличен максимальный размер файла (4 гб)". Файл весил 4.3 гб. Отформатировала флешку. Установила теперь с ФС NTFS. Все получилось. Но когда попыталась установить ОС на ноут выдаёт ошибку номер 13: "unsupported file system". Ноутбук старый, ~2004-2005 года, от IBM, BIOS тоже какой-то IBM-овский (не знаю на сколько это выражение правильно но пусть будет), всё 32-битное, non-pae. 
Помогите пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

WinSetupFromUsb на сколько я помню только виндовые загрузочные делает. Вам надо что-нибудь типа этого https://unetbootin.github.io/ или этого https://rufus.ie/